# Get custom element from slot

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have custom element with two buttons

```
<custom-elemen>
#shadowRoot
     <div class="form__buttons">
         <slot name="custom-button_cancel"></slot>
         <slot name="custom-button_save"></slot>
     </div>
#lightDom
<custom-button slot="custom-button_cancel"></custom-button>
<custom-button slot="custom-button_save"></custom-button>
</custom-element>
```

In button i get click listen

```
 link.addEventListener('click', events)
```

And events function

```
const events (events) => { 
 const slot = self.assignedSlot
}
```

In events function i get slot container

```
  const slot = self.assignedSlot
```

After that I'm in the slot tag

```
 <slot name="custom-button_cancel"></slot> in custom-element tag
```

How can i get parent custom element from slot ?

```
const slot = self.assignedSlot

And how can i get <custom-element> ?
```

Comment: Check [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot about this method.